# Passing passport generated user object to apollo server

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, apollo-server

I'm trying to configure my Apollo Graphql server to use Passport's Google OAuth strategy.

I've successfully configured passport such that I can access user information via `req.user` from within any of my express endpoints. However, when I try to access `req.user` from within the `/graphql` endpoint or from within the context method in the below ApolloServer, `req.user` is `undefined`.

```js
const gqlServer = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: ({ req }) => {
        // UNDEFINED
        console.log(req.user);
        // But still have typical headers
        console.log(req.headers);
    }
});
```

Am I missing anything that is preventing me from accessing request parameters in ApolloServer?

Comment: Are you calling `app.use` on the passport middleware *before* calling `gqlServer .applyMiddleware`?

Comment: Yes @DanielRearden

Comment: Is your client [configured correctly](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/#cookie) to send the cookies along with every request?

Comment: Was not. Had to add `request.credentials: include`. Feel free to post the answer and I'll accept.